# Gizmos only update when I hover over the scene or game view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script:

```
//Assets/TestScript.cs
using UnityEngine;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 a;
    public Vector2 b;
    public Vector2 c;
}
```

and it's editor script:

```
//Assets/Editor/TestEditor.cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(TestScript))]
public class TestEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        TestScript script = (TestScript)target;

        script.a = EditorGUILayout.Vector2Field("a", script.a);
        script.b = EditorGUILayout.Vector2Field("b", script.b);
        script.c = EditorGUILayout.Vector2Field("c", script.c);
    }

    [DrawGizmo(GizmoType.Active | GizmoType.Selected)]
    static void DrawGizmos(TestScript script, GizmoType gizmoType)
    {
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(script.a, 1.0f);
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(script.b, 1.0f);
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(script.c, 1.0f);
    }
}
```

It correctly shows the wire sphere gizmos, but when I edit the variables `a`, `b` or `c` the gizmos don't redraw unless I move my mouse over either the scene view or the game view. And even then it takes around a second.

The gizmos update properly when I remove the overridden `OnInspectorGui()` method.

I've tried adding `SceneView.RepaintAll()`, `HandleUtility.Repaint` and `Repaint()` to the beginning and end of the `OnInspectorGui()` method, but nothing changed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone on reddit showed me the answer.

The `SceneView.RepaintAll()` method will update only the scene view, whereas `UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility.RepaintAllViews()` will update all the views.

The update `OnInspectorGUI()` overridden method now looks like this:

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    TestScript script = (TestScript)target;

    script.a = EditorGUILayout.Vector2Field("a", script.a);
    script.b = EditorGUILayout.Vector2Field("b", script.b);
    script.c = EditorGUILayout.Vector2Field("c", script.c);

    if(Gui.changed)
        UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility.RepaintAllViews();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, you should create an **EditorWindow**

Here see it: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow-autoRepaintOnSceneChange.html

All **EditorWindows** have the following property: **autoRepaintOnSceneChange**

You can set it true, and it repaints the window when something has changed.
You can also call **Repaint()** manually in the Update() of the editorWindow